# should express http server be decoupled from rabbitmq consumer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rabbitmq

I need both an express server and a rabbitmq consumer for my application. My question is, whether it is beneficial to write both as seperate services, instead of combining them in one service. Does anyone have experience ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your requirements, but in general, if you create one service, it will be like an abstract layer between your application and the world. This is called a “gateway pattern”. Thus, there will be only 1 protocol between the application and the gateway (websocket, rest, grpc, etc.), and your application (clients) will be simpler than if you supported many other protocols in each new client. Some links https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html